# Scroll div with overflow y with image is distorting image in chrome and firefox but not safari

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have long image that I want to display in a container with a scroll bar. Perhaps I'm not going about this the right way, but at the moment I have a container(work-sample) with a project-container with the image inside. It displays fine in safari but for some reason when viewed in chrome and safari on macs, the long image is all scrunched together.

```css
#work-sample {
  flex: 1 3 auto;
  flex-basis: 3;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  padding-right: 1rem;
  padding-top: 1rem;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
}

.project-scroll {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  object-fit: cover;
}

#project-long {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="work-sample" class="work-sample">
  <div class="project-scroll">
    <img id="project-long" src="../media/incompatible-image.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you please create a minimum working example in Codepen or somewhere similar and share a link for the same so that the community can look into this more easily?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a height setting of 100% in the class for the img. This makes the img distorted as it's forced to fit that height. This snippet removes this so the height will default to auto and be shown in proportion to the overall image's aspect ratio.

```css
#work-sample {
  flex: 1 3 auto;
  flex-basis: 3;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  padding-right: 1rem;
  padding-top: 1rem;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
}

.project-scroll {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  object-fit: cover;
}

#project-long {
  width: 100%;
 /* height: 100%; REMOVED */
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="work-sample" class="work-sample">
  <div class="project-scroll">
    <img id="project-long" src="https://picsum.photos/id/1015/200/600">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is because `object-fit` is on the parent to your `img` but should be on `img` itself.

```css
#work-sample {
  flex: 1 3 auto;
  flex-basis: 3;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  padding-right: 1rem;
  padding-top: 1rem;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
}

.project-scroll {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

#project-long {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover; /* this property moved from .project-scroll */
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="work-sample" class="work-sample">
  <div class="project-scroll">
    <img id="project-long" src="https://generative-placeholders.glitch.me/image?width=1200&height=500">
  </div>
</div>
```